# How to replace seconds with hours:minutes:seconds?

Tags: replace

With milliseconds; before:

```
64.173
```

I want to get:

```
00:01.04.173
```

Another example: from

```
23032.3
```

I want to get this:

```
06:23:52.3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s#\d\+\ze\.#\=system('printf "%02d:%02d:%02d" $(('.submatch(0).'/3600)) $(('.submatch(0).'%3600/60)) $(('.submatch(0).'%60))')#g
```

`\d\+` mean one or more digits.

[\ze](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cze) mean the end of search pattern, `\.` after that is analog of look-forward for the dot.

Also here we use `#` as an [alternative delimiter](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Alternate_delimiters_for_the_replace_command) - because we already use `/` for division.

`\=` in the replace part mean that we will use [sub-replace-expression](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression).

`:h sub-replace-expression` is copied below:

```
Substitute with an expression           *sub-replace-expression*
                        *sub-replace-\=*
When the substitute string starts with "\=" the remainder is interpreted as an
expression.  This does not work recursively: a substitute() function inside
the expression cannot use "\=" for the substitute string.

The special meaning for characters as mentioned at |sub-replace-special| does
not apply except for "<CR>", "\<CR>" and "\\".  Thus in the result of the
expression you need to use two backslashes to get one, put a backslash before a
<CR> you want to insert, and use a <CR> without a backslash where you want to
break the line.

For convenience a <NL> character is also used as a line break.  Prepend a
backslash to get a real <NL> character (which will be a NUL in the file).

When the result is a |List| then the items are joined with separating line
breaks.  Thus each item becomes a line, except that they can contain line
breaks themselves.

The whole matched text can be accessed with "submatch(0)".  The text matched
with the first pair of () with "submatch(1)".  Likewise for further
sub-matches in ().
```

`printf` syntax: `02d` mean two digits: in will add leading zero when one digit.

`%60` mean reminder after division to 60.

See good article [Find, convert and replace dates with Vim substitutions](https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/vim-reformat-dates/).

Comment: For ffmpeg for cutting silence without reencoding: for decreasing of milliseconds against sound artefact: `:%s#inpoint .*\zs\d\+#\=submatch(0)-1#g`

Comment: Again for the case of ffmpeg about preparing file for silence cut: if you need to increase number of digits in milliseconds for safer/simpler decrease: `:%s#\.\d$#\=submatch(0).'0'#`

Comment: Why shell out with `system()`?  Vim can do math and has its own `printf()`.